# Struts2 Velocity Template Directory

Tags: java, struts2, velocity

Is it possible to have the .vm-files in a seperate directory?
... e.g. under the resources folder in a subdir like views?

When I do so and try to run the application, its not working.
It says, that it cant find the .vm-file.

I just want to prevent users from opening the plain .vm-files via the browser.

Usage:

```
<action name="test" class="com.acme.TestAction">
    <result name="success" type="velocity">test-success.vm</result>
</action>
```

Comment: Where do you use those template files? Show some code/conf.

Comment: They are configured in the struts.xml. Like so: `<action name="test" class="com.acme.TestAction">
    <result name="success" type="velocity">test-success.vm</result>
</action>`

Comment: Why should be *web* resource in the `resource` folder? Put them under `webapp` and inside `WEB-INF` to restrict direct access.